# How to reset the state in react when component is rendered or shown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to do the pagination part in my app, however the data is correct, but the only issue is when I try to call or show a component i.e **Trending.jsx** on click of a **button(Most Popular)** and ( type of toggle button),  at first it gets the correct page number, but when I hide that **Trending.jsx** component the page numbers remains the same, on my default **page/component which is Movie.jsx**

However, I want to **reset page number** if the component is not shown and start from 1 when a user clicks to see **Trending.jsx and viceVersa**

Please see the link to **code sand box** for the code I  tried.
https://codesandbox.io/s/moviehunt-demo-forked-rhom0?file=/src/components/Movies/Movies.jsx

**Full live app:**
https://rhom0.csb.app/movies

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, the problem is that when toggling back & forth between Movies & Trending, the Page Number is not getting reset to 1.

So, I created a useEffect with dependency on the state: **showTrending** in which I'm just updating the page number back to 1.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);
}, [showTrending, setPage]);
```

Also in order to update the Page Number in Pagination, I passed the page as prop to **PageNav** so it gets updated automatically. I hope this is the solution you are looking for.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/moviehunt-pagination-solution-hsc0f/?file=/src/components/Movies/Movies.jsx:2304-2305

Live: https://hsc0f.csb.app/movies

Also, I recommend adding some styling to the **Most Popular** Button so it's clear when it's Toggled On & Off.

Comment: Hi @ShivangamSoni  The solution seems to work as expected sir, only the page number at the bottom is not updated instantly, seems like only updates when main page is loaded, and also Just wanted to ask, can we use multiple useEffect in page or component? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a million for the quick reply and yeah this was the expected answer sir

Comment: Hi @TapeshPatel, yes you can use any number of useEffects as needed. and for the instant update I'll try to see into it too.